# CSS on draggable elements in JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx-2

I have a Pane in a JavaFX application. In this pane I draw [Lines](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Line.html) and I would like them to look more like pipes. In order to do so, I'm applying a gradient in a CSS file.

The extremities of my lines are draggable and therefore the lines can rotate.

Now the problem is when the lines rotate, the CSS gradient that I applied, does not stick to the line but stays static (it does not rotate at the same time), so I if put my line from vertical to horizontal, the style is completely different and wrong.

This is the property I'm using:

```
myLine {
   -fx-stroke-width: 10;
   -fx-stroke: linear-gradient(#e4fbff 0%,#cee6fb 10%, #a5d3fb 50%, #88c6fb 51%, #d5faff 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that is just the way CSS gradients work. They know nothing about the semantics of a 'start' or 'end' of a Node, but rather simply run from one point to another (e.g. the topmost coordinate to the bottommost coordinate).

As far as I know, the only way to achieve what you're trying to do is to set a new LinearGradient programmatically whenever you're dragging the line around - which will be computationally expensive.